# TLS connectivity log on MacOS

Tags: macos, logging, tls

Looking to enable TLS connectivity logging, mainly to identify the protocol version that is being used (TLSv1/2/3). OSLog (the new logging platform) does not log any TLS activity, unless directed by the application. for example, i see outlook generates TLS logs in the Console app. I would like to see additional usage, for example when I use openssl/curl etc...

any ideas on how to enable it?